# Backup and sync icon not showing on task bar.

Tags: backup, data-synchronization

Just got an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.4. I ran Migration Assistant from my old Mac Mini running El Capitan 10.11.6 and all seemed to work fine. However, the Backup and Sync icon on the toolbar is gone. I tried a couple of times to re-install the B&S program from the google website and it installed just fine each time but the icon is still missing. When I click on the Backup and Sync application in the Application folder it opens up the Google drive folder but still no icon on the task bar. Note, when i ran the Migration Assistant the Backup and Sync feature was 'paused'.

I am sure that this is a preference misbehaving but since preferences for B&S are shown through the B&S icon, which is not being shown on the taskbar, i can't see to review them. What can i do ? How can I review the preferences (B&S is not in the System Preferences)? Any other solution?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [4-finger salute](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) may help, but please refer to [this thread at Google support](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsTo4Dxp52aSByM). Be sure to open all the "more" buttons so you can read all the responses.